# Get path with specific number of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with the following values:

```
+---------+----------+
| post_id |   path   |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | 1/       |
|       2 | 1/2/     |
|       3 | 1/2/3/   |
|       4 | 1/2/3/4/ |
|       5 | 1/2/5/   |
+---------+----------+
```

How can I create a query that would get the path with the exact number of values separated by slashes?

For example, if I wanted all post_ids where the path is exactly `1/%/%/` (where each `%` represents a **single number**), meaning return anything of the form `1/2/3/`, `1/2/5/`, but not `1/2/3/4/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

**MySQL LIKE operator.**

The LIKE operator provides two wildcard characters, the percentage % ( match any string of zero or more characters), and underscore _ ( match any single character ).

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `path` LIKE '1/_/_/'

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `path` LIKE '1/%/%/'
```

**MySQL Regular Expressions.**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `path` regexp '^1/[0-9]/[0-9]/$'
```

**Hierarchical Data in MySQL**

Since this structure involves hierarchical data maybe you should consider to change the table structure to something that represents actual hierarchy. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ has an excellent tutorial about the subject.

Comment: Does `[0-9]` only check for values equal to 0-9 or does it also include much larger values, like 5,000?

Comment: Matches only one 0-9 characters, to match more than one use '^1/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/$'

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `regexp`:

```
select *
from yourtable
where path regexp '1/[0-9]/[0-9]/$'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0c28/4)

Comment: Does regexp need to be enabled somewhere for this to work, because I can't get it to show any results.

Comment: Also, your answer doesn't seem to work properly. I tried removing the second `[0-9]/`, and it's returning all results when it should only be returning one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0c28/7/0

Comment: @user4171336 -- sorry, left out the `$` for end of string... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0c28/9 -- in regards to `regexp` not working, I honestly don't know why...

Comment: I changed the values of the paths to something higher (2000) and the query no longer works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdce76/1/0

Comment: @user4171336 -- That's because [0-9] only matches on a single character (as we assumed from your post).  I see you now have the correct solution.  Glad we could help.